Big gap between the largest and second largest discovered Mersenne prime ($2^{136,279,841}-1$ and $2^{82,589,933}-1$)
Eighteen days ago, a new Mersenne prime was discovered by "Luke Durant", which is $2^{136,279,841}-1$. The discovery of the second largest Mersenne prime dates back to December, $7^{\text{th}}$,  $2018$, which is $2^{82,589,933}-1$. The following graph depicts the date of discovery versus exponent size.

Image source
So according to the graph, I wonder if there really isn't a Mersenne prime between $2^{82,589,933}-1$ and $2^{136,279,841}-1$. If this is the next consecutive Mersenne prime, then it would be interesting to see if there is any explanation for this big gap.

There are many primes between these two, but it may be difficult to prove this for an explicit one of the form $2^p-1$. Your second number below the image is divisible by $2$, so not a prime.

@DietrichBurde Actually my question was about if there are any "Mersenne prime" between the two numbers. I have edited my post and fixed that ambiguity and the typo.

On GIMPS Milestones you can track how many exponents need to be checked before all below $136,279,841$ have been checked at least once (currently 1 598). Until then, there might be some smaller Mersenne prime lurking.

The expected number of primes in that range is
$$
C=\sum_{82589933<p<136279841}\frac{e^\gamma\log(k_pp)}{p\log2}
$$
where $k_p=2$ if $p\equiv3\pmod4$ and $p_p=6$ otherwise.
The sum is about 1.373, so the heuristic chance that there would be no Mersenne primes in that range is $\exp(-C)\approx0.253$ or 25%. This is not particularly exceptional.
These are, of course, a priori numbers; if you consider the status of the testing done by the Mersenne project, you can refine this to a much smaller number by replacing the values in the summand with the respective error probabilities in cases where the numbers have already been tested or double-checked.
